# How to disable render MasterComponent every route change

Tags: angular

i have a dropdown menu :
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfsk8.png)

I want that keep open when user opens a menu, but if user changes the route by clicking another menus MasterComponent reloads itself, i want to disable it.
How can i do that?

**Note : if user navigates in the same route, mastercomponent wont reload, if user change the route, it happens.**

app.module.ts

```html
import {BrowserModule, makeStateKey} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MasterComponent} from "./components/master.component"
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import {ToastrModule} from "ngx-toastr";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {NgSelect2Module} from "ng-select2";
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
import {LoginComponent} from "./pages/login/login-component";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MasterComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DecimalPipe,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        NgSelect2Module,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientModule,
        AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "login"
            },
            {
                path: "login",
                component: LoginComponent
            },
            {
                path: "services",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/services/services.module").then(m => m.ServicesModule)
            },
            {
                path: "customer",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/customers/customer.module").then(m => m.CustomerModule)
            },
            {
                path: "parts",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/parts/parts.module").then(m => m.PartsModule)
            },
            {
                path: "operations",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/operations/operations-module").then(m => m.OperationsModule)
            },
            {
                path: "reasons",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/reasons/reasons.module").then(m => m.ReasonsModule)
            },
            {
                path: "invoices",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/invoices/invoice.module").then(m => m.InvoiceModule)
            },
            {
                path: "cars",
                component: MasterComponent,
                loadChildren: () => import("./pages/cars/cars.module").then(m => m.CarsModule)
            }

        ]),
        FormsModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
{
            path: "",
            component: MasterComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "services"
                },
                {
                    path: "services",
                    loadChildren: () => import("./pages/main-pages/services/services.module").then(m => m.ServicesModule)
                },
                {
                    path: "customer",
                    loadChildren: () => import("./pages/main-pages/customers/customer.module").then(m => m.CustomerModule)
                },
```